# 'Error Invoking Method' and 'Failed to launch JVM' error with java program packaged as EXE

Tags: java

First things first: **This is not a duplicate of [Error invoking method, failed to launch jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm) or [JavaFX application fail to launch with native exe bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004035/javafx-application-fail-to-launch-with-native-exe-bundle)**.

I am using Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.9 to pack my program as a EXE installer. When I tried to launch the program, it says "Error invokign method" and then "Failed to launch JVM".

> [image: error]
>   [image: failed]

I know relatively little about Java. I have a book that I read about how to program in Java and that's it. I know you have posted about this in other posts but I don't understand what these posts are saying.

Can someone explain how to fix these step by step please? I am running NetBeans 4.2 Update 2, Java JDK 1.8.0 172, Java SE 1.8.0 172 X86_64. I also have Java SE 1.8.0 151 X86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way around the problem. I used notepad to create a batch file to launch the app. First I used `cd` to get to the directory of the `.jar` file and then used `java -jar` to launch the app. Saved it as a `.bat` file on the desktop, launched the batch file and the program booted.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use NetBeans to deploy to exe just get the jar file and there is a plenty of apps to convert the jar to exe just like `launch4j`